# ALTER PROCEDURE with TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to modify approx. 24 huge UDP and for production deployment i need to do a BEGIN TRANSACTION / ROLLBACK / COMMIT PROCESS.

How can I add the `ALTER PROCEDURE my_proc` between BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT or ROLLBACK?

**Note**: `EXEC('ALTER PROCEDURE..')` can **NOT** be implemented.

Thanks

Update: there is a way to alter a procedure and rollback if it fails?

Comment: If you can't use dynamic sql, then you can't.  what's the restriction against dynamic sql?

Comment: Deployment team can not do EXEC under production

Comment: Then you can't do it.  Period.  Dynamic SQL is the only way to do what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Leandro, I’m adding a new answer because it would be too long for a compent)

I’ve been thinking. I don’t think this is a solution I would ever implement, but based on your requirements (and specially your restrictions), here is an idea that would work:

There is a modify_date on the sys.objects catalog so, why don’t you store the dates off all your objects before you run your updates and compare with the dates after you ran your updates. If ALL the dates are different, it means that all of them were updated correctly, if one of the dates is equal, it means that one failed and then you run a rollback script (you will need the rollback code, won’t be easy as just type ROLLBACK)

Answer (score 2):

why can't you the regular way.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE testProcedure
AS
    SELECT 1
GO

SELECT OBJECT_ID('testProcedure') ObjectID --this will return the object ID
GO

rollback TRANSACTION

SELECT OBJECT_ID('testProcedure') ObjectID  --this will return NULL because the proc creation was rolled back
GO
```

You cannot have BEGIN TRY and BEGIN CATCH around batches. However you can use the last batch to check that all previous steps have succeeded (by examining the catalog views like `sys.objects` for example). Then you can decide if the batch all succeeded and either commit or roll back.

Comment: `TRY ... CATCH` can't span batches but the OP doesn't mention `TRY ... CATCH` anyway.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, i don't want to create a procedure, i need do an alter procedure. Also it's fail because 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Comment: @Leandro: I guess, `CREATE PROCEDURE ...` in Diego's code snippet is just an example, you can use `ALTER ...` instead. As for your other point, this sample satisfies the requirement: `CREATE PROCEDURE` *is* the first statement, because it follows `GO`, which is a batch delimiter.